# Ayuda para instalar _version en python (Windows)

Tags: python

Estoy utilizando un script en `Python` y después de solucionar problemas con las tabulaciones ahora tengo uno en los módulos:

```
from mainLib import 
File "C:\Python35-37\mainLib.py", lin 
import mechanize *
File "C:\Python35-37\lib\site-package 
ImportError: No module named '_version'
```

¿Cuál es el nombre en `easy_install` para el módulo (implicando que sea un módulo)? No lo encuentro.

Comment: BIenvenido al sitio, en primer logar podrías aclarar que versión de Python estás utilizando y además debes agregar el código de tu programa que arroja dicho error para que te podamos ayudar. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Desafortunadamente, `mechanize` no funciona con python3. Tendrás que buscar alternativas como [robobrowser](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser) o [mechanical soup](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup)

Answer (score 0):

Porque no instalas python por medio de la distribución [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), ya viene con las bibliotecas incluidas y sin no viene con la que necesitas puedes usar `pip install` o `conda install` que están incluidos en esa distribución.